# Add method - MVC - working with data entry into two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent

I have two classes:

**User

UseP where** User have its id (PK) and UserP has the id (FK) of User.

I'm working on MVC 4. Using Fluent API.

The classes are mapped within the project to connect to the database. My project is split into controllers, services, models and views.

I have a User screen that uses a UserPr field.

1. How can I instantiate it in class without being the way down? (that way does not work because of the relationship, otherwise work):

   ```
   **CLASS USER.CS**

   public string Login { get { return this.UserP.login } set { login = value }}
   ```
2. inclusion screen to add the User of items, I should also change the status of the screen, this status is within UserP.

**Controller**

```
public ViewResultBase Add(User model)
        {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {

                    this.Service.SaveUserP(model);
                    return this.SuccessView(true);
                }
                catch (ValidationException exception)
                {
                    base.AddValidationErrors(exception);
                    return base.PartialView(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.PartialView(model);
            }
        }
```

**Service**

```
public void SaveUserP(User item)
        {
            //save fields from User (Running ok)
            base.context.Usuario.Add(item);

            //Attempt to save the login and their status in UserP
            foreach (var userP in base.context.UserP.Where(x => x.IdUser == item.Id))
            {
                item.login = userP.Login;
                userP.ParticipantType = 3;
                base.context.UsersP.Add(userP);
            }

        }
```

I've tried that way, but I could not.
If the item.login is only working because login stand as [notmapped] in User.cs

**To summarize:** In the inclusion screen (User) I have a field that should bring (UserP) login.

When I trigger the method of inclusion, he should save the fields and save the User log in using UsuarioP IdUsuario as key and also changing the status of login (ParticipantType = 3)

The error I get:

> Invalid column login (because really there is no login in User)

Time to debug it includes only the User fields, and even through the foreach.

I do not know how to operate, can help me? What if I have not been clear, I put more details

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the **User** input first before your foreach loop.

```
base.context.SaveChanges();
```